# How to format "MM/yyyy" pattern to locale-dependent "<month name> / yyyy" in SAPUI5?

Tags: date, localization, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I get dates from backend as data format "12/2019" and would like to convert in the format "Dez / 2019" ("Dez" in German, "Dec" in English). Has anyone an idea?

[image: Screenshot of SAPUI5 responsive table asking for date UI format]

Snippet from my XML view:

```xml
<cells>
  <Text text="{Period}" />
  <!-- ... -->
<cells>
```

`Period` is an OData V2 entity property and its EDM type is String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```xml
<Text text="{
  path: 'Period',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
  formatOptions: {
    pattern: 'MMM / yyyy',
    source: {
      pattern: 'MM/yyyy'
    }
  }
}" />
```

Here is a working demo (Click on <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>):

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
], Fragment => Fragment.load({
  definition: `<Text xmlns="sap.m"
    text="{
      value: '12/2019',
      type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
      formatOptions: {
        pattern: 'MMM / yyyy',
        source: {
          pattern: 'MM/yyyy'
        }
      }
    }"
  />`
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script><body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

Since the EDM Type of `Period` is String, simply using [`sap.ui.model.type.Date`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.type.Date) should be sufficient in this case. If the Type is however `Edm.DateTime`, which is usually used to represent date values in OData V2, then the type `sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime` should be considered.